# Calculate price per square metre

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I'm selling rolls that come in two widths. The user can choose which width is required however the user can also type in the length in metres. Then a price is calculated.

For instance if the price is £5 square metre, and the user chooses the 4m option and types in a length of 4.5m then the total cost should be 5 x 4 x 4.5

Is there an existing extension, is this simple to program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both of the extensions mentioned by @Marius, and I can say that they *might* meet your needs. In my case, they were not robust enough for us to use.

I ended up having to write my own solution, here's the basic flow:

- Created a custom product type
- Custom product type uses it's own template for the `product_type_data` block where I can include my own form fields for the user to enter dimensions.
- Custom product type main model class has a `setPrice` method where I can use my own calculations to determine the price
- I have an observer on the `sales_quote_add_item` event where I can take the request and pass it along to the `setPrice` method.
- The custom product type's `type` model uses `_prepareProduct` to add the user's choices as custom options added to the `additional_options` option.

This should be enough to get you started. Depending on your requirements, there might be additional things to code so that, for example, a user is able to edit their choices when clicking the "edit" button in the cart.

Comment: Hi Pspahn - Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately i'm a complete newbie in Magenta, could you some assistance on the code ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used or tested this, but you can give it a try, or at least investigate further:  http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-length-area-volume-pricing-calculator.html. It claims it does what you need (price per surface) and more: price per volume, support for different unis of measure....
This one also claims the same: http://www.micosolutions.com/advanced-variation-pricing.
I haven't used any of these and I'm in no way associated with the developers. I just found these on a quick search.